# Do you need to account for the sinusodial projection when working with MODIS?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp, modis

I am currently working on a project where we analyse the vegetation cover of the whole of Canada and the US. We have used MODIS data. Only now did I read that the usage of MODIS data leads to possible image distortion associated with the sinusoidal projection for mid-latitude regions in for example Canada ([Pouliot et al. 2014](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.rse.2013.10.004)).

Do I have to account for this and therefore reproject the data into Canada Lambert Conformal Conic projection?
If so, the gdal Warp adds additional pixels to the image and changes the values a tiny bit. How can I account for that/reproject it properly?

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr

vegetation = "path/vegetationcover.tif"
out = "path/vegetationcover_102002.tif"
x = gdal.Warp(out, vegetation, dstSRS = "EPSG: 102002")
x = None
```

Comment: I have found this [page](https://code.env.duke.edu/projects/mget/wiki/SinusoidalMODIS) very useful, especially with setting the required transformation that is needed to project the data correctly. You don't appear to be setting this as you call the warp tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the effect of the distortion in places like Alaska. However, what you're doing with `gdal.Warp` is right (if that's your target projection!).

You can fix the extent and resolution with the `outputBounds` and `xRes`/`yRes` options (`-te`  and `-tr` if you use `gdalwarp` the command line), otherwise `gdal.Warp` makes a decision on it. Make sure you also use `resampleAlg="near"` in Python or `-r near` if using the command line.